# Finding integral of product

Tags: integration

How do I find the integral of $x^3e^{3x}$, with the limits $1$ and $0$? I know I can't use u-substitution, because I have tried to do so. My teacher however said I shouldn't use integration by parts, so which other method can I use?

Comment: I would use integration by parts. Why not?

Comment: I also have the limits 1 and 0. Which makes integration by parts difficult

Comment: I don't see why. Anyway, you did not mention that in your post.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos "My teacher however said I shouldn't use integration by parts"

Comment: **Hint**
Using Rieman Integral : $$
\int^1_0 x^3 e^{3x} dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{k=0} f\left({\frac{k}{n}}\right)$$

Comment: (I disagree with your teacher) Integration by parts works, you just have to work/induct your way up. Find $ \int e^{3x} \, dx, \int xe^{3x} \, dx, \int x^2 e^{3x} \, dx , \int x^3 e^{3x} \, dx$ (You don't need the limits)

Answer (score 0):

**Reduction formula**

By the product rule, we have
$$
d\left(x^n e^{3 x}\right)=3 x^n e^{3 x}+n x^{n-1} e^{3 x}
$$
Integrating both sides yields $$
\begin{aligned}
x^n e^{3 x} & =3 \int x^n e^{3 x} d x+n \int x^{n-1} e^{3 x} d x \\
& =3 I_n+n I_{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearranging gives
$$
\boxed{I_n=\frac{1}{3}\left(x^n e^{3 x}-n I_{n-1}\right)},
$$
by which we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_3 & =\int x^3 e^{3 x} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{3}\left(x^3 e^{3 x}-3 I_2\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{3}\left[x^3 e^{3 x}-3 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\left(x^2 e^{3 x}-2 I_1\right)\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{3}\left[x^3 e^{3 x}-x^2 e^{3 x}+2\cdot\frac{1}{3}\left(x e^{3 x}-I_0\right)\right]\\&= \frac{1}{27} e^{3 x}\left(9 x^3-9 x^2+6 x-2\right)+\text { constant }
\end{aligned}
$$